# apache throws 404 - does not get to rewriting rules

Tags: php, apache, mod-rewrite, redirect

Here is an issue i'm having:

- my virtualhost is configured to rewrite non-existing files to /init.php?REQUEST. Eg: www.test.com/module/action would rewrite to /init.php?module/action. This is a pretty common functionality, achieved by:

  ```
  <Directory /path/to/test.com/htdocs/>

    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ init.php?$1

  </Directory>
  ```
- now i'm trying to open this:

  ```
  location.href = 'http://www.test.com/module/action/' + encodeURIComponent('htp://www.google.com/');
  ```

But now apache throws a 404 page without even getting into the rewriting part.

- Fact 1: it happens because of the %2F symbol (a forward slash)
- Fact 2: apache doesn't even get into <Directory> rule. It is obvious that we want something under htdocs/ so why doesn't apache get to the directory rules ???

Could someone please explain it to me why the slash symbol messes things up?

Thanks for your thoughts

Comment: Is it in right VirtualHost directive ?

Comment: Your rules work fine for me, and it returns my init.php script. But does your 404 have something to do with the google url being malformed? `htp://www.google.com/`

Comment: @CappY yes - it is in the right directive :)

Comment: @JonLin nooo ... it doesn't get far enough to notice that. google is just an example - the real url is not malformed, but the %2F symbol is definately the one causing problems. If i don't urlencode it - it works fine! I wonder if apache version (Apache/2.2.17) could have something to do with it ...

Answer (score 2):

Hate to answer my own question, but i woke up with a fresh head this morning and solved it ...

- Problem: appears that %2F is not valid in any URL. Apache needs a special directive to process it (AllowEncodedSlashes perhaps?)
- Solution 1: replace %2F with %252F after encoding
- Solution 2: don't encode %2F at all (is not good for my case)
- Solution 3: pass %2F into the query string instead (not good for my case as well)

So if someone runs into this in the future - now you have a few solutions to choose from :)